# Groovy Execute a closure inside if statement even if the if statement is false

Tags: grails, groovy, functional-programming

I have the following code:

```
    if (false) {


        request.withFormat {

        //Code Here             
        }
}
```

The closure executed here even if it is false. Is this a correct behavior?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide an example which executes as you say?  I can't get it to do so.  What version of Groovy btw?

Comment: I'm using springsource 3.1 with groovy 1.8 compiler.

Comment: Please show the entire method. I can't re-create that behavior.

Comment: you may want to shove a println in your withFormat, just to be sure that's really executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if that is truely happening it is not correct behavior.

Test it to be sure by putting in a println, if it still fails, report it.  I can't get the same code to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If(false) won't let flow to go inside if block, but I have seen this with below code

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/ajkumar/Desktop/")
  println "${file.isFile()}"
  if("${file.isFile()}")
  {
      println "it's a file"
  }
  else if("${file.isDirectory()}")
  {
      println "it is a directory";
  }
```

This code prints :
false
it's a file
I am also clueless why it's happening.